# Can't boot 19.04 after installing 2nd ext4 drive

Tags: boot, ext4

I have a 19.04 machine. I tried adding a second hard drive that is ext4. When the machine boots it gets to a blink cursor on black screen and no further. The drive was previously the system disk for 16.04 but I have replaced the partition table and formatted as ext4.

Another post suggested checking if the drives UUID is in /etc/fstab. It is not.

I am able to add a second NTFS drive. And the machine does boot.

[image]

I tried another drive with ext4 and the machine would not boot.

Both of the ext4 drives function fine if plugged into an external USB dock.

Comment: go into the BIOS (right when you press power, before anything is on screen start hammering `del` or `F2` or whatever your BIOS key is.) once inside reorganise the Boot priority. your drive containing grub must be first. is this a dual boot system?

Comment: It is not dual boot. The 1st boot priority is 'hard drive', the remaining are 'disabled'. The machine is a Dell. There is no option to pick a specific hard drive.

Comment: well that sounds wrong it shouldn't say "hard drive" it should at least say it's manufaturer and size (on EFI bios it could even says the OS, but you're clearly not on EFI) and none of them should be as "disabled", switch them on, and figure out which one is the one with the OS installed then move it up the list (it'll tell you what key to press, it couldd be F8 or something)

Comment: Added image of boot options. this is with 2 hard drives connected. Yes, my laptop which is Asus shows the actual drive but this system doesn't as far as I can tell.

Comment: this is just awefull if asus has a new BIOS version for your laptop flash your motherboard with it because this is unworkable.

Comment: oops, I wasn't very clear on that. The bios picture is my desktop, a DELL so I'm stuck with it. The Asus is a different machine, my laptop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should just rewrite your entire question. it's not clear what you're saying and you forgot too much crucial information. people aren't going to read the coments. you need to make your question ledgible. I've been getting the details from you and even I don't know whta's going on